# Synchronization not working

Tags: java, multithreading

I've created a very simpel calculator for learning purposes where I want an "announcer" to announce the result of the operation in a JTextArea. The purpose of this program is to utilize the things we have been learning in University. I have a own announcement class that implements runnable and synchronize my calc object and it's supposed to append the result but nothing happens.

The program is working fine so I've stripped the code to the relevant parts:

The run method inside the announcer class:

```
    public void run()
{
    calc.getAnnouncementJTF().append("Announcer thread has been initialized...\n");
    calc.getAnnouncementJTF().append("Hi. My name is " + this.getName() + " and my purpose is to " +
            "announce the results of your operations as soon as they are ready. \r\n");
    while(true){
        synchronized(calc){
            try
            {
                calc.wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        calc.getAnnouncementJTF().append(String.valueOf(calc.getResult() + "\n"));
    }

}
```

And here is the conditional that will perform the calculation and notify all waiting objects:

```
            else if(e.getSource() == sumButton && Numbers.size() != 0)
        {
            if(!actualNumber.getText().equals("")){
                Numbers.add(new Double(actualNumber.getText()));
                addToResults = previousNumbers.getText() + " " + actualNumber.getText();
            } else {
                addToResults = previousNumbers.getText().substring(0, previousNumbers.getText().length() - 2);
            }
            currentResult = performCalculation(Numbers, Operators);
            previousCalcs.append(addToResults + " = " + String.valueOf(currentResult) + "\r\n");
            // Clear both lists and add the result to a cleared
            // list for further calculation on it.
            Operators.clear();
            Numbers.clear();
            actualNumber.setText(String.valueOf(currentResult));
            previousNumbers.setText("");
            resultExist = true;
            synchronized(this){
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
```

Main method

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Announcer announcer = new Announcer();
    Calculator calc = new Calculator(announcer);

    calc.setTitle("Calculator");
    calc.setSize(360, 900);
    calc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    calc.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    calc.setVisible(true);
    calc.setResizable(false);

    announcer.setCalculator(calc); announcer.setName("Sam");
    announcer.setAge(28); announcer.setLength(182.5);

    Thread announcerThread = new Thread(announcer);
    announcerThread.start();
}
```

As I mentioned before the code is running fine. The only problem I have is that this part of the run method in announcer class is not run:

```
calc.getAnnouncementJTF().append(String.valueOf(calc.getResult() + "\n"));
```

Comment: You have synchronization issues in your class, but you also have a big Swing problem: Swing components may not be accessed from a thread other than the EDT. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: Move the `calc.getAnnouncementJTF().append()` inside the `synchronized` block. And, as @JBNizet stated, us `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` to update the text outside of the EDT. Where is the "condition" called?

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments, the code modifying the UI state must be executed in the event dispatch thread. But I guess, you are already doing the update in the EDT. In this case the problem is that you are running an infinite loop polling for new results and appending them to the `JTextField`. That works, but you are blocking the event dispatch thread with your infinite loop so it has no chance to ever repaint the affected UI area.

A simple solution is to let the calculation thread schedule `Runnable`s using `EventQueue.invokeLater` which will just perform a single update and return. Another way is to let a Swing `Timer` execute a `Runnable` periodically which will synchronize on the `calc` object and ask for the current result. Note that in the latter case, like in the code you have now, you might miss updates as `notifyAll` is not guaranteed to be paired with `wait` calls of other threads.

Further, it is not enough to synchronize just for the `wait` and `notify` calls. The code which modifies the result and the code which retrieves the result (the `calc.getResult()` invocation) must be inside the `synchronized` block as well.